# Map function is not working inside the .then()

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, map-function

I have two functions as following
function 01

```
export const generateProductList = async (products: IProduct[]) => {
    const productList: IProduct[] = [];
    products.map((product: IProduct, i: number) =>{
        downloadImageAwsS3(product.image)
            .then(res => {
                productList.push({...product, image: res})
            })
    })
    console.log(productList)
    return productList
}
```

function 02

```
const productGenerator = (products: IProduct[]) => {
    const checkoutList: any[] = [];
    generateProductList(products)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        res.map(product => {
          checkoutList.push(product)
          console.log(product)
        })
    return checkoutList
  })
  }
```

in the second function inside .then() and inside the map function is not working properly,
Can anyone help me to figureout this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: consider using `async-await`

Comment: It is working fine, but you are printing your list before the callback was executed ...

Comment: in function 2  ```console.log(res)``` give the output

Comment: What do u mean: is not work properly?

Comment: Ignoring the log statements, the code simplifies to `const productGenerator = generateProductList;`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `response = res.json()` inside `.then()` sometimes response comes in readstream.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say given that you provide little context as to the issue that you're facing. What do you expect, and what are you seeing?

I'll take a guess and say that the `generateProductList` method is returning before it's finished mapping all of the `products`, assuming `downloadImageAwsS3` method returns a Promise.

You can try returning `Promise`s from `products.map`, so that each product in `products` is mapped to a `Promise`, then wait for all of those promises to settle with [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

```
export async function generateProductList(products: IProduct[]): Promise<IProduct[]> {
  const productList: IProduct[] = [];
  await Promise.allSettled(products.map(async (product: IProduct) => {
    const response = await downloadImageAwsS3(product.image);
    productList.push({...product, image: response});
  }));
  return productList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not waiting for the results of promises. Both `downloadImageAwsS3(product.image)` and `generateProductList(products)` are returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Also, the [map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

A correct version of your code would be something like this:

```
export const generateProductList = async (products: IProduct[]) => {
  const promises = products.map(async (product: IProduct, i: number) =>{
      const res = await downloadImageAwsS3(product.image);
      return {...product, image: res};
  });
  const productList = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(productList)
  return productList;
}
```

The second function doesn't make a whole lot of sense, because it's just returning the results of the first one, but if you want to map over the values and do something you can do it like that:

```
const productGenerator = async (products: IProduct[]) => {
   const productList = await generateProductList(products);
   const convertedProducts = productList.map((product) => {
     console.log(product)
     // return a new value here
   });
   return convertedProducts;
}
```